# Is there any socket functions to connect automatically a client to a server, when the server switches off and on again?

Tags: c#, winforms

It would be a great help if i get an idea for my problem. I am using a server and client application. I am using Berkley Sockets . My problem is now when my server switches off or disconnects from the client , my client throws out an exception.

> "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An established
>   connection was aborted by the software in your host machine    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginSend(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, SocketFlag socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>   at CCLink_Structure.Form1.Send_Message_Timer_Tick(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in C:\Users\yilia\source\repos\CCLink Structure\CCLink
>   Structure\Form1.cs:line 494    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
>   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

My client wants to remain stable even when the server switches off and my client should connect back to the server automatically when the server switches on.
I am developing a user interface program in c# windows form application. In my program i use form. timer to send the data continuously to the server , the interval time between data packets is 50 ms . My only problem now is that i want my client to standstill without throwing any exceptions and should reconnect when the server switches on.

````
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Connecting...";
    Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    String IP = System.Convert.ToString("192.168.68.110");
    int Port = System.Convert.ToInt32("54601");
    IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP),
                Port);
    newsock.BeginConnect(iep, new AsyncCallback(Connected), newsock);
}
 catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }```
````

Comment: This approach looks like typical XY problem. You are trying to minimize the consecuences of a problem but you should instead look why the hell the server goes down.

Comment: Servers go down all the time for maintenance so you have to be able to handle cases when the server goes down.  Then you are have to loop until the server goes back up by either periodically attempting to connect or ping the server until you get a response.

Comment: I am using the form.timer function for sending the data packets. and I have included the connection function inside the Form.Load . so how do i do that . i tried using Keep alive function.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is resilience and retry functionality.
This you need to code yourself into your program.

You could try to use 3PP libraries such as Polly to help you with this.
https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

But I agree with the comments, that you should probably look at why the Server is going down.  If this is planned maintenance, then you should look at a High-Availability solution where you have your server deployed in a resilient 1+1 or N+1 manner.